# Has the concept of bodily integrity been discussed in the context of the human-nature relationship?

Tags: political-philosophy, dualism, environmental-philosophy

Human rights and many constitutions protect humans' bodily integrity. The concept is regularly linked to personal autonomy, freedom of movement and choice ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodily_integrity)).

The idea that the origin and scope of human action are that centred on the human body considered in isolation arguably does not reflect the reality of human existence as an integral part of an ecosystem. Indeed, references to autonomy, freedom of movement and choice seem to imply that bodily integrity *does* require a link to nature, i.e. access to vital resources elsewhere in the ecosystem to ensure both the physiological and psychological well-being.

So I wonder if the concept of bodily integrity has been discussed in the wider, systemic context of the human-nature relationship? There is an emerging discourse of a vital [right of access to nature](https://search.proquest.com/openview/84388ff3dca68d05ea207bc13ebc3cf8/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=33885). But I'm looking for a more integral, less dualist-environmental, discussion.

Comment: Some cultures/societies have their focus on individuals over society - but not all. Some cultures/societies stress the group over the individual. The group's right. The manifestation of the individual autonomy is most realized in today's world in the US. Part of its manifestation is this stress on individual rights and individual autonomy. The concept that this is universal, for all human beings, is called Universalism. It is not. You are a product of your own upbringing.